# Get value from radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a multiple select radio but the output to the console is console=on.

That doesnt help at all. I need to know which (none,t,i or ti) that is selected.

Any idea how to do this?

```js
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
  var data = $('#containerCreationForm').serialize();
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="containerCreationForm" method="post">
  <div class="content-form">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Console</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="radio radio-info">
          <input name="console" id="it" class="form-control" type="radio">
          <label for="it">Interactive &amp; TTY
                                                            <span class="text-blue">(-i -t)</span>
                                                        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio radio-info">
          <input name="console" id="tty" class="form-control" type="radio">
          <label for="tty">TTY
                                                            <span class="text-blue">(-t)</span>
                                                        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="radio radio-info">
          <input name="console" id="interactive" class="form-control" type="radio">
          <label for="interactive">Interactive
                                                            <span class="text-blue">(-i)</span>
                                                        </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio radio-info">
          <input name="console" id="none" class="form-control" type="radio" checked="">
          <label for="none">None</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="#btnSubmit">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: You've not specified a `value` attribute on any of the radio buttons, so the default is used - ie. `on`. Also note that `id="btnSubmit"` is not valid. Remove the `#` in there

Answer (score 0):

You need to use names and values to identify what your radios mean
eg

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(
    function(args) {
      args.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).serialize());
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Gender:</legend>
    Male: <input type="radio" name=gender value=m> Female: <input type="radio" name=gender value=f> Other <input type="radio" name=gender value=o>
  </fieldset>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

this will result in a form value of gender= m | f | o

also note you should be using the forms submit event as this will invoke the forms validation logic which your current code is bypassing

Comment: what do you mean? I always used a button click to submit. What's the difference?

Comment: HTML 5 introduced required  (see:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) and a few other validation routines that preprocess forms before submitting the data

Answer (score 0):

Add `value` attribute in radio button.

Example:
Since,you are using Jquery in your code. I'm using it here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue){
                alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
            }
        });

    });
```

In HTML:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</label> 
<label><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female</label>

    <p><input type="button" value="Radio Value"></p>
```

Hope it helps..!